# How to sort each row in a dataframe from the smallest to largest number

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe that I would like each row to be sorted from smallest to largest numbers and still remain in the same row and the same numbers but just sorted out. Here a example I have below.

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrRIJ.png]

As you can see in the image is that each row has numbers that are not in order.

I would like my result to be something like this.

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDIRL.png]

Comment: How can dataframe rows have different number of numbers? (4, 6, 4 in your example)

Comment: I dont see no 4,6,4

Comment: len(3,4,24,34) = 4, len(1,5,7,12,20,21) = 6

Comment: Please post your `df.head(3).to_dict()` instead of this cvs you provided

Comment: ok i update the post . hopefully i made better sense this time

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can do this:

```
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: sorted(x), axis=1)
```

But in your example, it seems that each rows has a different number of items (4, 6, 4), which doesn't make sense.

Comment: doesnt work the way i need it to . i updated my post so hopefully it works this time

Comment: @outkast20 Post your code with this line as an attempt to solve the problem, and I'll see what can be done further.

Comment: i had to convert to list to get it to worked. thank you so much